# How do I fix touchscreen issues after upgrading to 21.04 from 20.10?

Tags: drivers, touchscreen, bug-reporting, 21.04

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 from 20.10. But after the upgrade, the touchscreen of my laptop (HP Pavilion) has started to misbehave in odd ways. It has started registering touch inputs even when I am not touching the screen at all. As a result, it randomly opens dialog boxes, or the top notification and date panel, or will randomly resize the windows...

Is there any solution to the problem, is this a common / known issue? Are there any solutions?

Comment: If it's a reported/known issue it will be found on launchpad which is the bug tracker.  Have you looked?   This isn't a bug tracker. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Sorry, i'll make the needed changes / addition of info. But I am not sure about the command to use to check the screen details..searching..